# Strange "Member function not viable" error in templated linear algebra vector class

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I'm implementing a templated vector class (not the data container, but the vector in the linear algebra sense), and I'm getting quite a few errors whenever I refer to `rhs` in my operator overloading. Also, my copy constructor doesn't seem to be working.

```
#ifndef __VecXd__VecXd__
#define __VecXd__VecXd__

#define ULL unsigned long long
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class VecXd
{

public:

    explicit VecXd(ULL newDimension = 1) { dimension = newDimension; vector = new T[newDimension];}
    VecXd(const VecXd<T> &rhs);
    VecXd<T>& operator=(const VecXd<T> &rhs);
    const VecXd<T> operator+(const VecXd<T> &rhs) const;
    VecXd<T>& operator+=(const VecXd<T> &rhs);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, VecXd<T> vec);
    friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, VecXd<T>& vec);
    ~VecXd() { delete[] vector; }

    const ULL getDimension() { return dimension; }
    const T itemAtIndex(ULL index) { if(index >= dimension) throw 1; return vector[index]; }

private:

    ULL dimension;
    T *vector;

};

template <class T>
VecXd<T>::VecXd(const VecXd<T> &rhs)
{
    dimension = rhs.getDimension();
    vector = new T[dimension];
    for (ULL i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
        vector[i] = rhs.itemAtIndex(i);
}

template <class T>
VecXd<T>& VecXd<T>::operator=(const VecXd<T> &rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs)
    {
        if (dimension != rhs.getDimension())
        {
            delete [] vector;
            dimension = rhs.getDimension();
            vector = new T[dimension];
        }
        for (ULL i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
            vector[i] = rhs.itemAtIndex(i);
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
VecXd<T>& VecXd<T>::operator+=(const VecXd<T> &rhs)
{
    if (dimension != rhs.getDimension())
    {
        cout << "\nCannot perform addition. Vectors do not have the same dimensions.\n";
        throw 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for (ULL i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
            vector[i] += rhs[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
const VecXd<T> VecXd<T>::operator+(const VecXd<T> &rhs) const
{
    VecXd<T> temp = *this;
    temp += rhs;
    return temp;
}

template <class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream &outs, VecXd<T> vec)
{
    for (ULL i = 0; i < vec.dimension; ++i)
        out << vec.vector[i] << (i+1 < vec.dimension ? " " : "");
    return out;
}

template <class T>
istream& operator>>(istream &in, VecXd<T> &vec)
{
    ULL newDim = 1;
    cin >> newDim;
    if (!cin.good())
    {
        cout << "\nImproper input.\n";
        throw 1;
    }
    else
    {
        delete [] vec.vector;
        vec.dimension = newDim;
        vec.vector = new T[vec.dimension];
        for (ULL i = 0; i < vec.dimension; ++i)
            in >> vec.vector[i];
    }
    return in;
}

#endif /* defined(__VecXd__VecXd__) */
```

I'm getting errors of this style:

`Member function 'getDimension' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const VecXd<int>', but function is not marked const`

This happens every time `rhs` calls a function (such as `getDimension()` or `itemAtIndex()`); two error appear (once for `VecXd<int>` and another for `VecXd<int>`).

Also, the copy constructor is not recognized in the overloaded +operator function in this line:

```
VecXd<T> temp = *this;
```

Help?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To be able to call a function on a `const` object, you need to promise the compiler that the function will not modify the object. To do that, you mark the function with the keyword `const` after its argument list. For example, to make `getDimension` a `const` member function, you would change it to:

```
const ULL getDimension() const { return dimension; }
```

(Note that the `const` in the return type will have absolutely no effect, so you should get rid of it)

Comment: And the `const` before `ULL` seems to be superfluous here. (maybe a misplacement?)

Comment: @dyp That might have been their attempt to fix the error.